# PyYAML: Working with Yaml having unusual constructor tags

Tags: python, yaml, tags, pyyaml

I have a YAML file containing the following data:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:something.com,2019:
--- !u!1337 &1
MainKey:
  B: 0
  Z: 2
  C:
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
```

To work with this YAML, I created a constructor, and a representer. After loading, then dumping the file, I obtain the following result:

```
!<tag:something.com,2019:1337>
MainKey:
  B: 0
  C:
  - a: 0
    c: 0
    e: 0
  - a: 1
    c: 1
    e: 1
  Z: 2
```

I have two questions:

- First: How can I keep the header, and constructor tag identical to the original version ?
- Second: How can I make sure the keys are dumped in the same order, instead of being sorted ?

Here is the code I am working for this example, so it can be reproduced:

```
import copy
import yaml

from io import StringIO
from typing import Dict, Type, TextIO


class Foo:

    tag = "tag:something.com,2019:1337"

    def __init__(self, obj: Dict) -> None:
        self.obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Foo'):
        return self.obj == other.obj

    @staticmethod
    def loader(yaml_loader: yaml.SafeLoader, node: yaml.nodes.MappingNode) -> 'Foo':
        decoded_dictionary = yaml_loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
        return Foo(decoded_dictionary)

    @staticmethod
    def representer(dumper: yaml.SafeDumper, foo: 'Foo') -> yaml.nodes.MappingNode:
        return dumper.represent_mapping(Foo.tag, foo.obj)


YAML_FILE = """%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:something.com,2019:
--- !u!1337 &1
MainKey:
  B: 0
  Z: 2
  C:
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
"""

EXPECTED_FOO = Foo({'MainKey': {'B': 0, 'Z': 2, 'C': [{'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'c': 0}]}})


def get_loader() -> Type[yaml.SafeLoader]:
    yaml_loader = yaml.SafeLoader
    yaml_loader.add_constructor(Foo.tag, Foo.loader)

    return yaml_loader


def get_dumper() -> Type[yaml.SafeDumper]:
    dumper = yaml.SafeDumper
    dumper.sort_keys = False
    dumper.add_representer(Foo, Foo.representer)

    return dumper


def load(file_pointer: TextIO) -> Foo:
    return yaml.load(file_pointer, Loader=get_loader())


def dump(foo: Foo, file_pointer: TextIO) -> None:
    yaml.dump(foo, file_pointer, Dumper=get_dumper())


def test_can_load():
    with StringIO(YAML_FILE) as file_pointer:
        result = load(file_pointer)

    assert result == EXPECTED_FOO


def test_can_dump():
    with StringIO() as file_pointer:
        dump(EXPECTED_FOO, file_pointer)
        file_pointer.seek(0)

        assert file_pointer.read() == YAML_FILE


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_can_load()
    test_can_dump()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using ruamel.yaml (disclaimer I am the author of that package) for
this kind of round-tripping. Apart from preserving comments it also preserves directives
if you use the same `YAML()` instance  for loading and dumping.

You can, but don't need to, make constructors and representers (if you do you lose the comments).

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

file_in = Path('input.yaml')


class UnEscape:
    def __init__(self, tags):
        self._revmap = {tag[0] + tag[1:].replace('!', '%21'): tag for tag in tags}
        # print('revmap', self._revmap)

    def __call__(self, s):
        for k, v in self._revmap.items():
            s = s.replace(k, v)
        return s
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(file_in)
unescape = UnEscape(yaml.tags)
data.anchor.always_dump = True   # only necessary because there is no alias in the example 
data['MainKey']['C'][1]['c'] = 42
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=unescape)
```

which gives:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:something.com,2019:
--- &1 !u!1337
MainKey:
  B: 0
  Z: 2
  C:
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 42
```

The transform parameter to dump is necessary to revert the escaping of the ! in the middle of the tag
(which normally comes out as `!u%211337` which is equivalent, but not nice for a diff).

If the derictive is always the same, you can also transform using the simpler:

```
def unescape(s):
    return s.replace('!u%21', '!u!')
```

The tag is preserved (you have to set always dump to dump it if there is no corresponding
alias that would force the anchor to be dumped).
There is however no control over the order of the anchor and the tag. `!u!1337 &1` loads
the same as `&1 !u!1337` and `ruamel.yaml` always dumps the latter as that makes it clear
you have an anchor on the tagged construct and not a tag on anchored construct.

`ruamel.yaml` always preserves the order of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using yaml. You are passing (loading it) as a `Foo` object.

So `pyyaml` attempts to [sterilise](https://realpython.com/lessons/serializing-objects/) it.
Just like the [pickle module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pickle-python-object-serialization/).
Try to pass it as a `dict`.

SideNote: Be careful when using `pyyaml` as it is unsafe as pickle. And such can result in unwanted code execution.

So it is best to call `yaml.safe_load` instead of `yaml.load`

So. Try this:

```py
import copy
import yaml

from io import StringIO
from typing import Dict, Type, TextIO

YAML_FILE = """
MainKey:
  B: 0
  Z: 2
  C:
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
  - a: 0
    e: 0
    c: 0
"""

EXPECTED_FOO = {'MainKey': {'B': 0, 'Z': 2, 'C': [{'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'c': 0}]}}

def test_can_load():
    with StringIO(YAML_FILE) as file_pointer:
        result = yaml.safe_load(file_pointer)

    assert result == EXPECTED_FOO


def test_can_dump():
    with StringIO() as file_pointer:
        yaml.dump(EXPECTED_FOO, file_pointer)
        file_pointer.seek(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_can_load()
    test_can_dump()
```

conclusion:
If you want to store data(classed) it is best to use pickle
If you want to store json compatable data with human readability then it is best to use yaml

**I am sorry If I misunderstood your question.**

Comment: Because my example is simplified you could do it that way. However this is not applicable to my case, the first reason being that I am not the original file owner, and it has a constructor tag. So I have to implement both a constructor and a representer. This forbid me to use safe_load, but it's not an issue because I use yaml.SafeLoader and yaml.SafeDumper.

Comment: Oh. sorry. my bad. I misunderstood the question.
(Now that it see it. it is very confusing to me too. )